# Board Game Capturing Pieces

Tags: java, chess

I am creating a boardgame which has two different coloured pieces, black and red.

If a player surrounds the opponents pieces with his own, either horizontally or vertically, the pieces are removed. Here are some pictures to demonstrate this:

My board is a simple 2d integer array, with values of 0, 1 or 2 depending on whether the space is empty, has a red piece or a black piece.

This is the code I have come up with so far, however I am getting issues with out of bounds errors and it also does not account for capturing more than one piece.

```
static final int EMPTY = 0, BLACK = 1, RED = 2, ROW = 9, COLUMN = 9;
board = new int[ROW][COLUMN];

public void captureRedPieces() {
    for(int i = 0; i < ROW; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < COLUMN; j++) {
            if(i <= ROW - 2) {
                if(board[i][j] == 1 && board[i + 1][j] == 2 && board[i + 2][j] == 1) {
                    board[i + 1][j] = EMPTY;
                }
            }
            if(i <= COLUMN - 2) {
                if(board[i][j] == 1 && board[i][j + 1] == 2 && board[i][j + 2] == 1) {
                    board[i][j + 1] = EMPTY;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Could anyone help me come up with a better solution for capturing pieces?

Answer (score 1):

You are testing whether `i <= ROW - 2`, but then you are using `i+2` as an index for your check. This means that if `i` is 7, which is equal to `ROW - 2` and passes your `if` test, then `i+2` will be `9`, which is out of bounds because the array only goes 0 to 8.

So you should correct this to `i < ROW - 2` rather than `<=`.

Also, you have this code:

```
      if(i <= COLUMN - 2) {
            if(board[i][j] == 1 && board[i][j + 1] == 2 && board[i][j + 2] == 1) {
                board[i][j + 1] = EMPTY;
            }
        }
```

This should be a condition on `j`, not on `i` - and it has to be fixed in the same way I told you about `i` - `<` instead of `<=`.

**Note**: since your rules state that a "surrounding" state is a capture only after the surrounding color makes a move, perhaps you should change your approach: you should only check the position where black made a move, to match with positions around it. Of course, you'll still have to make sure you don't go out of bounds. Your current approach might mark places that are "surrounded" since previous moves, and that would be wrong per the rules.

So your method should be declared like so:

```
public void captureRedPieces(int blackMoveRow, int blackMoveCol )
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have to replace `i <= COLUMN - 2` with `j <= COLUMN - 2`. Seems that capturing occurs after the new move. If you know the exact position of the new piece, then no need to iterate over the whole board. You just need to check nearby pieces in the same row and in the same column where the new piece was placed.